# .catch() in http.get not catching HTTP 500 error code

Tags: angular, observable

In my Angular 2 app, I have a Service with an `http.get` method that returns an Observable.

**campaign.service.ts**

```
public getCampaign(campaignId: string): Observable<Campaign> {
  return this.http.get(this.campaignsUrl + '/' + campaignId, options)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.data || body || {};
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
  // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    const body = error.json() || '';
    const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

I then call it in my Component, like so:

**campaign.component.ts**

```
this.campaignService.getCampaign(paramId)
  .subscribe(
    obj => {
      // do something
    },
    () => {
      // handle error here
    }
  });
```

However, if the `http.get` call returns a HTTP 500, I never hit my `.catch(...)` section in my Service class. Console outputs an uncaught exception.

```
GET http://localhost:9001/api/v1/campaigns/4175edc4 500 (Internal Server Error)
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL: http://localhost:9001/api/v1/campaigns/4175edc4
Uncaught Response {_body: "{"message":"invalid input syntax for uuid: \"4175edc4\""}", status: 500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers…}
```

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: In debug mode, which one is hitted; `this.extractData` or `this.handleError` or none of them? Can you also provide these two methods in question?

Comment: @ulubeyn, in debug, none are hit. I've also added details about the two methods.

Comment: What is the console output of error? And when you return 200, does this work?

Comment: I added the console error messages above. And yes, 200s are handled correctly.

Comment: I have the same exact problem with a POST request. Did you come to any good solution ?

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 5):

Angular 2 follows the Fetch spec, which [only throws errors when there was a problem with the request operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful). It does not throw if an error response was returned (as an error response is still a valid response).

You need to check the `response.ok` attribute to ensure it is not 404 or 500 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Declared functions are assigned a global context if they aren’t declared within the context of an object. So when we want our closure (inner function) to refer to one of our parent objects, we either have to preserve the value of the object or bind the object to the function.

Try this:

```js
.catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```